# How to highlight Javascript missing brackets calling function

Tags: javascript, debugging

In the following HTML/Javascript snippet, I'm missing the function's brackets in the onclick statement (it should read: `onclick="showMessage()"`).

How could I get the missing brackets highlighted

(a) in Notepad before I display the page.

(b) in my Browser JS console after I display the page?

If this is not possible besides inspection, is there another way I could identify this issue more easily?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showMessage() {
            document.getElementById("messageArea").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Show message" onclick="showMessage">
    <div id="messageArea">---</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `onclick` takes any kind of javascript expression, function execution being one of them. For example:

```html
<script>
    var a = 10
</script>

<!--All are valid and don't throw any errors -->

<button onclick="a">Nothing happens</button> 
<button onclick="a++">Increment</button> 
<button onclick="alert(a)">Check value</button>
<button onclick="undefined">Surely Not?</button>
```

Executing functions like `showMessage()` is one of it's primary use. And technically it's not an error to have a `showMessage` without the `()` inside the `onclick`. `showMesage` is just function definition, If you were to type `showMessage` and press enter in your browser's console, it will simply return the function definition and won't throw any error. So IDEs don't underline it as an error because it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool that will look at html attributes for possible errors like this.

However, if you move all of your javascript code to a separate file, you can use a tool like [eslint](https://eslint.org/) to check for common errors.

So in this case, instead of using the `onclick` attribute in your HTML, you'd use javascript to select the element and add an event listener.